# Java - How to correctly display ANSI art in a JTextPane

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, jtextpane

I am having trouble displaying [ANSI art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_art) in a `JTextPane`.

I thought simply chosing a fixed-width or monospace font and removing line-spacing of the `JTextPane`'s `StyledDocument` via a `SimpleAttributeSet` would be enough to correctly display [some different pieces of ANSI art](http://pastebin.com/0De5Wnds), but after trying different fonts and settings I realized it has to be more than that.

I've been using [DAMN NFO Viewer](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Damn-NFO-Viewer_58116681.html) to compare my `JTextPane` with in order to see if my code is displaying [the piece of digital art](http://pastebin.com/0De5Wnds) correctly.

I set the `JTextPane` font to the same font DAMN NFO Viewer is using (according to its settings *Courier New, 8*, by default) via `artTextPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 0, 8))`. However, even if I apply line-spacing settings via `StyledDocument.setParagraphAttributes(int, int, AttributeSet, boolean)` my `JTextPane` does not display the art correctly.
Here is two screenshots to show the differences:

**DAMN NFO Viewer (Courier New, 8):**

[image: DAMN NFO Viewer Courier New 8]

**My `JTextPane` (Courier New 8)**:

[image: JTextPane Courier New 8]

What is really strange is that when I am setting my `JTextPane`'s font-size to 9 the alignment seems to be correct but a bit unsharp. Zooming onto the characters that form the **g** in the art piece shows blueish pixels to the right that make it look unsharp:

**My `JTextPane` (Courier New 9)**:

[image: JTextPane Courier New 9]

Also I noticed that opening the [art.txt](http://pastebin.com/0De5Wnds) in notepad displays it just like DAMN NFO Viewer does. Also the `JTextPane` seems to be displaying it smaller, like, the 'casket' in which a character is drawn appears smaller.

First I thought DAMN NFO Viewer is using a different version of the font *Courier New*, so I dug through its directories and found the following registry file:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\DAMN\DAMN NFO Viewer\NFO]
"FontName"="[built-in] Courier New"
"FontData"=hex:91,00,03,01
"Window"=dword:00000023
"BackgroundColor"=hex:ff,ff,ff,00
"TextColor"=hex:00,00,00,00
"HyperLinkColor"=hex:bf,cd,db,00
"HyperLinkHoverColor"=hex:99,b4,d1,00
"Text"=dword:00000400
```

Which makes me think it may use a derived version of *Courier New* with the settings `"FontData"=hex:91,00,03,01`. However I have no idea how to reproduce that derivation in Java.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong trying to display a text file in a `JTextPane` the same way **DAMN NFO Viewer** does it?

**EDIT:**
Added some test/example code that I am currently working with, trying to get the font displayed "correctly" (in a way that does not deface the ANSI art). I created this test GUI using [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/)'s built-in GUI builder "Mantisse", so it may not be a perfect example but it should clearly show the difference to the screenshots of DAMN NFO Viewer.

```
package jtextpanetest;

public class JTextPaneTestUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JTextPaneTestUI
 */
public JTextPaneTestUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    textPanesSrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
    textPane.setText("▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄\n███████▄▄▄▄ ▀▀▀▄▄\n▄ ▀█▓█████████▄▄ ▀▀█▄\n █  ▓█▓▄ ▀▀█▓███▓▄  ██\n  █ ▒▓▒▓    ▒█▓█▒▓  █▓█\n  █ ░▒░▒█ █ ░▓▒▓░▒█ █▒▓█\n  █ ░░░░▓ █ ░▒░▒░░▓ ▓░▒█\n  █ ▒░▒░▒ █ ▒░░░▒░▒ ▒░░█\n  █ ▓▒▓▒░ █ ▓░▒░▓▒░ ░▒░█\n  █ █▓█▓▀ █ █▒▓▒█▓░ ░▓▒█\n  █ ██▀ ▄▀█ █▓█▓██  ▒██\n  █ █ ▄▀▄█  █████▀  ▓█\n  ░ █ ░ █ ▄██▀▀ ▄▄█ █░\n  ▒▄▄▄▒ ░▄▄▄▄▄▀▀  █ █\n          █ ██▀ ▄▀                   \n          █ █▌▄▀  \n          ░ █ █                  \n          ▒▄▄▄░ \n\n █████████\n███████████\n███████████\n███████████\n█████ █████\n█████ █████\n█████ █████\n█████ █████\n█████ █████\n███████████\n███████████\n ██████████\n     ██████\n███████████\n██████████      ");
    textPanesSrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);

    panel.add(textPanesSrollPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JTextPaneTestUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JTextPaneTestUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTextPane textPane;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane textPanesSrollPane;

}
```

**EDIT2:**
Someone suggested me to render the art as image, but I need it to be editable, so that is not an option I guess. Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that text in JTextPane is rendered with too much space between lines. The same issue would arise with other widgets. The actual spacing depends on the font (and therefore the JVM). The blue blur that you can observe with Courier 9 is probably caused by anti-aliasing.

Your code renders like this with Java 1.7.0_55-b13 on MacOS X:
[image: Original rendering]

With a JTextPane, you can reduce the line spacing as follows (before calling JTextPane.setText):

```
javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet set = new javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet(textPane.getParagraphAttributes());
javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, (float)-0.1);
textPane.setParagraphAttributes(set, false);
```

The -0.1 value fixes the line spaces, you might need another value for another font or font size.

[image: Removed space between lines]

You may need to reduce the tracking (the space between letters) as well:

```
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 0, 8);
java.util.Map<java.awt.font.TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new java.util.HashMap<java.awt.font.TextAttribute, Object>();
attributes.put(java.awt.font.TextAttribute.TRACKING, -0.1);
java.awt.Font font2 = font.deriveFont(attributes);
textPane.setFont(font2);
```

[image: Rendering with tracking]

Comment: What I already did was setting the line spacing using `StyleConstants.setLineSpacing()`, which resulted in the blurry, unsharp displaying of the art and did not remove the line spacing for all sizes (between 9 and 16) of a certain font (Courier New). Maybe I need to add different spacing values for different sizes of the given font? I'll try adding tracking when I find some spare time and let you know about the results.

Comment: `TextAttribute.TRACKING` is actually very useful to get rid of small gaps between the characters that occure on different sizes of "Courier New", but using it I still couldn't reproduce the looks of the font in DAMN NFO Viewer. I'll do some more testing and update the question with more information.

Comment: Oh gash, I've just noticed that copying the art from a *.nfo file had special characters displayed as `[BEL]` in notepad++ in it, which defaced the art when changing the front size from 9 to anything else. Replacing these with whitespaces turns out to make it displayable in different sizes without getting defaced. I am going to run more tests, I think I might be able to get it working now, using your suggestion with the `TRACKING`.

Comment: Allright it works, I just have to set different spacings and trackings for different fonts/sizes, which is a bit of a pain as there's a lot of different combinations. Thank you!